# Delete zip file after download in zf2

Tags: php, download, zend-framework2, zip

I am trying to delete zip file after downloading it. I try the following code. But it shows error

```
$response = new \Zend\Http\Response\Stream();
$response->setStream(fopen($zipname, 'r'));
$response->setStatusCode(200);
$headers = new \Zend\Http\Headers();
$headers->addHeaderLine('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream')
        ->addHeaderLine('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename='.basename($zipname))
        ->addHeaderLine('Content-Length', filesize($zipname));

$response->setHeaders($headers);
unlink($zipname);
return $response;
```

After download, while I open the downloaded file in notepad, it shows like:

> unlink(D:\xampp\htdocs\medgenom\development\uploads/Bulk_formE_Download_0.91481200 1474869559.zip): Permission denied in

Comment: Looks like you are deleting the file before sending the response to the client? And you should really show us the error you're getting...

Comment: I updated the question @MagnusEriksson

Comment: Just like the message says, it seems like the user your running PHP with doesn't have permission to delete the file.

Comment: No, I can delete other files using unlink function. The issue occured while deleting the zip file created using php. @MagnusEriksson

Answer (score 0):

I solved using the following code

```
header('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".basename($zipname));
header('Content-Length', filesize($zipname));
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
readfile($zipname);

unlink($zipname);
```